# how data with file through work in ajax jquery post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I upload an image in Php through jQuery post ajax method? I tried this code in simple way but it did not show in file data and not stored in directory ,even it is stored in database. Its all data through in form

```
        <form  id="Myform5" method="POST" action="" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data">
                              <label >Class</label>
                           <select name="type" id="Class">
                           <option >Choose option</option>
                           <option value="Matric">Matric</option>
                            </select>
                             <input  type="text" id="Institute_Name" >
                                 <label >Institute Name</label>
                            <input type="text"  id="Board_Name">
                            <label  >Board Name</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Starting Year</label>
                         <select name="type" id="Starting_Year" >
                              <option >Select year</option>
                              <option value="1950">1950</option>
                         </select>

                                <label>Ending Year</label>
                                <select name="type" id="Ending_Year" >
                               <option >Select year</option>
                               <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                </select>

                     <input  type="text" id="Total_Marks" >
                         <label>Total Marks</label>
                  <input  type="text" id="Obtained_Marks" >
                  <label >Obtained Marks</label>

                                <label>Result_Card</label>
                      <input type="file" id="Result_Card" 
                    id="file"  class="inputbox" placeholder="Default Input">

                      <textarea  id="Awards_Honors" type="text" ></textarea>
                              <label >Awards & Honors</label>
                  <textarea  id="Co-curricular" type="text"  ></textarea>
                              <label >Co-curricular</label>
                   <textarea   id="Additional_Info" type="text" ></textarea>
                              <label >Additional Info</label>
                      <button  type="button"  id="button4" >
```

its juery ajax post

```
       $("#button4").click(function(){
  var Class = $("#Class").val();
  var Institute_Name =$("#Institute_Name").val();
  var Board_Name=$("#Board_Name").val();
  var Starting_Year = $("#Starting_Year").val();
  var Ending_Year =$("#Ending_Year").val();
   var Total_Marks=$("#Total_Marks").val();
   var Obtained_Marks = $("#Obtained_Marks").val();
  var Result_Card =$("#Result_Card").val();
  var filename = Result_Card.replace(/^.*\\/, "");
   console.log(filename);
  var Awards_Honors=$("#Awards_Honors").val();
  var Co_curricular = $("#Co-curricular").val();
   var Additional_Info =$("#Additional_Info").val();

if (Class.length == "" || Institute_Name.length =="") {
   alert("Fill the form");
}
else
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url :'view2.php',

        data : {
            Class:Class,
            Institute_Name:Institute_Name,
            Board_Name:Board_Name,
            Starting_Year:Starting_Year,
            Ending_Year:Ending_Year,
            Total_Marks:Total_Marks,
            Obtained_Marks:Obtained_Marks,
            filename:filename,
            Awards_Honors:Awards_Honors,
            Co_curricular:Co_curricular,
            Additional_Info:Additional_Info
        },
        // cache: false,
        // contentType: false,
         enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        // processData: false,
        // enctype:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success : function(feedback){
         console.log(feedback);
          alert("sucess");
            $("#Myform5")[0].reset();
        }

    })
 }});
```

now i give this page of php

```
  if (isset($_POST['Class']) && 
          isset($_POST['Institute_Name']) &&    isset($_POST['Board_Name']) 
      && isset($_POST['Starting_Year']) && isset($_POST['Ending_Year'])  
        && isset($_POST['Total_Marks']) &&  isset($_POST['Obtained_Marks'])
          &&  isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['Awards_Honors']) &&
      isset($_POST['Co_curricular']) ){
     /*Uploading FIle OF Image or other in jpg jpeg png size 2 MB */
                                         $errors= array();
                            $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
                            $file_tmp =$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
                            $file_type=$_FILES['filename']['type'];   

   $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['filename']['name'])));    

    $expensions=   array("jpeg","jpg","png","txt","pdf","docx","bmp",
                                          "gif","jpeg","jpg");     

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
            $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a 
      JPEG,txt,pdf,docx,bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg or PNG file.";
                                        }
      if(empty($errors)==true){

      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"files/".$file_name);
                  echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";     
                                        }else{
                                            print_r($errors);
                                        }echo"<br />";
                 $Class = $_POST['Class'];
                 $Institute_Name= $_POST['Institute_Name'];
                 $Board_Name = $_POST['Board_Name'];
                 $Starting_Year= $_POST['Starting_Year'];
                 $Ending_Year = $_POST['Ending_Year'];
                 $Total_Marks= $_POST['Total_Marks'];
                 $Obtained_Marks = $_POST['Obtained_Marks'];
                 $filename = $_POST['filename'];
                 $Awards_Honors = $_POST['Awards_Honors'];
                 $Co_curricular = $_POST['Co_curricular']; 
                 $Additional_Info = $_POST['Additional_Info'];                     
               $sql=" INSERT INTO `secondary level` 
               (`Class`,`Institute_Name`, `Board_Name`, `Starting_Year`,
              `Ending_Year`, `Total_Marks`, `Obtained_Marks`, `Result_Card`,
                `Awards_Honors`, `Co-curricular`, `Additional_Info`) VALUES
                ( '$Class', '$Institute_Name', '$Board_Name', 
                  '$Starting_Year', '$Ending_Year', '$Total_Marks',
              '$Obtained_Marks','$filename','$Awards_Honors',
                '$Co_curricular ','$Additional_Info' )";

          if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
       }}
```

Comment: I think you should check "How to ask a Question" before posting your whole code.

Comment: Sorry dear i am new in stackoverflow but you check question what i tell you

Comment: Its okay youre new ... but before posting a question there was a link "How to ask question" you should read it if you want someone to answer your question. It should be asked clearly and you should go straight to the point. No one can fix your whole code. Im just trying to help you no offense

Answer (score 0):

just provide name attribute to each element in the form and change input type button to submit then use this:

```
$("#Myform5").submit(function(a){
    a.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
   $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'view2.php',
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                location.reload();
                },
                error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                }
            });

});
```

this may upload image without posting your text data on your local machine but it will work on web server.

Comment: thank you given this code i want to try above code in simple way instead of new form() object.

Comment: This is the simplest way. You don't have to change backend file for using this code.